# Can I omit an object after 'those who + verb?'

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, ellipsis, objects

1. Those who speak English respect *those who don't speak English*.
2. Those who speak English respect *those who don't speak*.
3. Those who speak English respect *those who don't*.

I believe the first and third are correct, but the second is not okay in terms of grammar.

Could you tell me your opinions? I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You are correct. 1 and 3 are good, 2 is not.

Comment: They are all correct "in terms of grammar". In 2., "those who don't speak" has the incorrect meaning of "people who never talk (about anything ever)".

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is grammatically correct: let's assume that it has the meaning that you want to convey.

> Those who **speak English** respect those who don't **speak English**.

As you can see, the phrase **speak English** occurs in both the first clause and the second. You can therefore make the third sentence using [verb phrase ellpisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), because **speak English** in the second clause is a repeat of one that occurs in an earlier clause.

> Those who **speak English** respect those who don't.

In the second  sentence, you are omitting only the object of the verb: you can't do that without changing the meaning, because the [speak a language](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speak) meaning is transitive only, so an object is required. As gotube commented, the second sentence is still grammatically correct, though the meaning is different. This is because the verb **speak** also has the meaning "say words": this meaning can be intransitive, so no object is required.